# How to get all the contents inside an HTML tag?

Tags: jquery, variables, get

How to get this codes that are inside a parent tag. For example:

```
<div class="main">
   <p>This is a sample photo <img src="sample.jpg" /></>
</div>
```

How to get all the contents that is inside `<div class="main">`, this also includes the attributes etc.? This code,`<p>This is a sample photo <img src="sample.jpg" /></>` , and place it inside a variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var html = $('.main').html();
```

Should do it

This will return the innerHtml of the first element found with a class of `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Using plain old Javascript, you can get the HTML contents with innerHTML.  Using JQuery to select that particular element, you could use:

```
Content = $(".main")[0].innerHTML;
```

You may need to add some more code in case there is no element found, or if you want to loop through all the elements with class = main.